# How to show label and icons over the polygon?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

[image]

I am working with angular-4 application. To display map I used **@types/googlemaps** npm package. Refer this [link](https://medium.com/@svsh227/integrate-google-api-map-in-your-angular-2-4-5-app-472bf08fdac) for more details.

As my requirements I have to display shape (polygon) over the map. It was done by using [Drawing Tools](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools) of google map. Now my question is how to display text and icon box on polygon as displayed in above image. I tried with [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple) of google map but infowindow is different compare to the box which displayed in above image.